# Python: how to drop duplicates with duplicates?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following

```
df
     Name  Y
0     A    1
1     A    0
2     B    0
3     B    0
5     C    1
```

I want to drop the duplicates of `Name` and keep the ones that have `Y=1` such as:

```
df
     Name  Y
0     A    1
1     B    0
2     C    1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `drop_duplicates` method,

```
df.sort_values('Y', ascending= False).drop_duplicates(subset=['Name'])
```

Comment: drop_duplicates has by default keep ='first' , so your proposition will keep 0's instead of 1's. You should either sort in descending ordrer , or add a keep='last' argument in drop duplicates

Comment: Agree, will etit

Answer (score 2):

#### `groupby` + `max`

Assuming your `Y` series consists only of `0` and `1` values:

```
res = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False)['Y'].max()

print(res)

  Name  Y
0    A  1
1    B  0
2    C  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Does  'Y' column contain only  0-1? In that case, you can try the following :

```
df = df.sort_values(['Y'], ascending= False)
df = df.drop_duplicates(['Name'])
```